# Ajax php login only works with an alert();

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a very weird problem with my ajax login. Below I have provided the code to login. 
The wierd thing is:

If I remove the alert("???"); I do not get a response from checklogin.php while it's getting the correct parameters to login.

If the alert("???"); remains in the function the page checklogin.php replies with "success" and website.php is loaded!

Basicly it does not enter the ajax success when there is no alert().

I have been looking at this for hours now and I have no idea what the alert triggers to make this work.

It still gets all the correct parameters, but the php does not reply without the alert. I have tried putting a sleep in the ajax using 'beforeSend', it also did not work.

Thanks in advance!

AJAX function:

```
    function checkSwipedCredentials(decryptedCredentials)
{   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'checklogin.php',
        data: decryptedCredentials,
        success:function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'success')
                    {
                        document.location='website.php';
                    } else {
                        showSwipeForm(); //onfailure
                    }
                }
    });
    alert("???");
    return false;
}
```

PHP-code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1)
{
    echo "success";
    $_SESSION['username']=$username; 
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " I do not get a response from checklogin.php"? What Firebug says?

Comment: Firebug shows that there was no response, with the alert() there firebug shows response: success

@F4r-20 : exactly, that is the wierd thing... But still the alert makes evrything work :/

Comment: I would add that your design is flawed as it's not secure. There is no point using ajax to check credentials and then re-direct immediately to another page that doesn't test for credentials. You might as well have a standard form where the check is done on the load of 'website.php'. It would then be secure.

Comment: Can you give more context, such as where you are calling said function? I suspect you are running it in an event such as form submit or an anchor tag click, but not properly preventing the event from doing it's default action. The alert would give it enough time before the page is left for the ajax to complete, but without the alert the ajax gets aborted immediately. You really shouldn't use alerts for debugging for this very reason. It gives you a false sense of direction when you begin debugging. The problem you are having has nothing to do with the alert.

Comment: Just fyi, I fixed it. The function was called on a form.submit, which refreshed the page before the ajax request could be handled! So I removed the form and used a normal button and it's working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return false;`.  There is no reason you would need to do this.  The alert is suppressing the effect of it.

Comment: I submit that the return false probably prevents the default action of a link being clicked.

Comment: Then use the JQuery method `preventDefault` instead. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I have removed the return false; but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what the alert does: it adds a pause before the function returns false. This pause is as long as you need to click OK and this could be enough for the AJAX request to be processed (remember this happens asynchronously).

PHP replies most certainly exact like it should. The response only does not get evaluated correctly anymore.

Now the remaining question is:   how do you call this function so that the return value has these side effects?

Answer (score 0):

The alert is preventing the page from further action while its present. This tells me that there is an issue caused by "return false;" or something else on the page is conflicting with the ajax call after the call is made. The alert's presence allows the ajax call to complete before its interrupted. I suggest you isolate this functionality and place it on a test page alone to work out if this code has an issue. I suspect it will work once isolated.

Comment: I have found something new, if in firebug I click on the POST which did not get a response and I choose "send again" it gets a correct response...

So that's what the alert() triggers probably, it triggers a page refresh. But why am I not getting a correct success response the first time?

Comment: I don't see the problem in the code you present. Have you isolated the functionality on another page and tested it?